# Prove completing the square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, problem-solving

Prove that:
$x + y + xy - x^2 - y^2 \leq 1$

If I use $-x^2 + xy - y^2$ to start completing the square, I get: $x + y -((x+y)(x-y)) - xy$

I am confused on how to keep going.

Comment: Any constraints on $x,y$?

Comment: Please keep your tags relevant to the topic. Do not use more tags strictly for visibility.

Comment: @Newb nope... real numbers

Comment: This isn't really an "analysis" problem, nor is it a discrete mathematics problem (and definitely not an open problem). It could however be a multivariable calculus problem. Where is this originating from?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Problem-Solving class, and we are looking right now at the real numbers. This subject just came out in this problem.

Comment: @OrchidFibio Then this should be labeled as algebra-precalculus or multivariable-calculus or problem-solving, but this most definitely not a discrete mathematics problem (since discrete mathematics is concerned with.. discrete objects and the real numbers are anything but discrete) nor an analysis problem.

Comment: @CameronWilliams cool.. that sounds even better. Sometimes is hard to find the right and more appropriate tags.

Comment: Are you familiar with multivariable calculus? (It can be very useful here.)

Comment: @CameronWilliams I did calculus a long time ago, so I am kind of remembering again. I know what you mean, but I don't remember it.

Comment: Hint: $\frac12(x-y)^2+\frac12(x-1)^2+\frac12(y-1)^2\ge0$.

Comment: A common trick in this sort of situation is to note that a sum of squares is always positive. Move the variables to the right hand side so you have $0\leq \textrm{some expression}$, then try to rewrite that expression as a sum of squares (and perhaps a positive constant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\begin{align}
f(x, y)
&=x+y+xy-x^2-y^2\\
&=x+y-xy+2xy-x^2-y^2\\
&=x+y-xy-(x-y)^2\\
&=1-1+x+y-xy-(x-y)^2\\
&=1-(x-1)(y-1)-(x-y)^2\\
\end{align}
$

If we can show that
$g(x, y) = (x-y)^2 + (x-1)(y-1) \ge 0$,
we are done.

$\begin{align}
g(x+1, y+1)
&=(x-y)^2 + xy\\
&=x^2-xy+y^2\\
&=x^2-xy+y^2/4 + 3y^2/4\\
&=(x-y/2)^2+3y^2/4\\
&\ge 0\\
\end{align}
$

so we *are* done.

Answer (score 2):

$$x + y + xy -x^2 -y^2 = -\frac{1}{4} \left((x + y  - 2)^2 + 3(x-y)^2\right) + 1 \leq 1$$